# home loans and title problems

Tags: loans

Me and a family member bought a house with both names on the title but my family member names is on the loan, now we want to change the title and loan to my name only, but I heard we can not do this because my name is on the title already. We want to take his name off the title as well and get a loan in my name only. Can this be done ?

Comment: Too vague; please edit to provide more detail. What country is this in? Are both names currently on the loan and you want to remove the family member, or it is only the family member's name on the loan? If your name wasn't on the loan to begin with, why not? etc.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the name(s) on the loan can usually be done only by refinancing -- taking out a new loan that pays off the previous loan.